# Remove trailing comma from concatenated query string result

Tags: php, sql, trim

hope you can help, tearing my hair out here!

I have...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT this FROM that');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['this'] . ',';
    }
```

Which returns...
222,225,243,256,260,269,273,280,295,296,

I need to remove the last comma to give me just...
222,225,243,256,260,269,273,280,295,296

I've tried `trim` `rtrim` `substr` and everything else I could find but none of them work. Think it's to do with the concatenation of the `$row['this'] . ','` but I cant figure out how to resolve it!

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use implode

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $a[]= $row['this'];
    }

$b = implode(',',$a);

print_r($b);
```

function for implode

```
function imp($c){
        $d= implode(',',$c);
        return $d;
    }


$b = imp($a);

print_r($b);
```

Comment: How could I put that whole thing into a function so I can call it whenever I need it?

Comment: Thanks Arun, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just let MySQL do the work for you:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(this, ',') as thises FROM that');
```

This constructs the results as a comma-delimited string.  You can refer to it by its name, `thises`.

Comment: `thises`... Not `these`? XDDDDDD But seriously, top thinking G

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds an interesting way to do it but could't get it to work (As you can probably tell, I'm not an avid coder!)

`$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(this, ',') as these FROM that');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
  echo $row['these'] . ',';
 }
`

Comment: Either name the column `these` in the subquery or fetch it uses `thises`.  I just made your example plural because I figured it was really named something else.

Answer (score 1):

Use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove last comma.

```
rtrim($my_string,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substr()**

**This is your code**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT this FROM that');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   echo $row['this'] . ',';
}
```

**Code Should like this**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT this FROM  that');
$my_string = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   $my_string .= $row['this'] . ',';
}
$my_final_string = substr($my_string, 0, strlen($my_string)-1);
echo $my_final_string;
```

**Explanation**

```
 substr(string,start,length)
```

**string** = Your generated string

**start** = From which position you want to start the string.

**length** = A positive number - The length to be returned from the start parameter. Negative number - The length to be returned from the end of the string

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried it but it returns...
222225243256260269273280295296
(Removes all commas)

Comment: Hi Sorry just a silly mistake, Now rectified. Please check. If you have issue please get back to me